# can't install QGis in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gis, ubuntu-12.04, qgis

I can't install QGis in ubuntu12.04. I got following error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install qgis
[sudo] password for anju: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
qgis is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnss3-dev libnspr4-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 574 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up qgis-providers-common (1.8.0-1~precise2) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: pj_ctx_alloc
dpkg: error processing qgis-providers-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-providers:
 qgis-providers depends on qgis-providers-common (= 1.8.0-1~precise2); however:
  Package qgis-providers-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing qgis-providers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1.8.0-1~precise2); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-globe:
 qgis-plugin-globe depends on qgis (= 1.8.0-1~precise2); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing qgis-plugin-globe (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                         ration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 1.8.0-1~precise2); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers-common
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-globe
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the gem is installed, but its dependencies aren't configured properly.

Try running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure qgis` to reconfigure them.

Comment: I tried this command but got   $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure qgis  
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: qgis is broken or not fully installed

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in the following link, it fixed the symbol look up error in qgis.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1764127

Answer (score -1):

If I remove QGIS, then I can't re install it back!

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question -- perhaps you should post this as a comment?